# Connecting to a remote IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have a WebSphere Application Server 8.5 instance running on my machine with a deployed app. I'm trying to go the the url of the app to test the code I've just written, but I'm trying to do it from a remote machine.

This remote machine is the only one with permissions to Internet Explorer 11 (I'm in a corporate environment), which is what I need to test my application in.

Here's the URL that I'm using to test the app from IE 8 locally: 
`http://localhost:9082/app/login` and it works fine.

On the remote machine with IE 11, I just replaced localhost with my IP (I also tried host name) and expected it to load, but it never does. I get back an unable to connect error. I can ping my local machine from the remote one so I know they're able to see each other.

I talked with our network administrator guys here and they don't know of any firewall settings (we're using a corporate firewall not the Windows Firewall) that would cause this to happen. So I'm thinking this has to be a WebSphere setting.

What settings do I need to have in the WebSphere admin console or in a config file that will allow it to accept remote connections?

Comment: Are you able to access the application on the machine in which WebSphere is installed with IP address? Did you configure Virtual Host for the deployed application?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari, Yes, I am able to access it using the IP from the local machine. No I haven't configured a Virtual Host for the deployed application. How do I do that in the Admin Console?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari, I found where the virtual hosts are setup. There is a default virtual host with a lot of aliases. Each alias has * as the host name though.

Comment: If you are able to connect locally using your ip then it is firewall/network issue. Either you have firewall incorrectly set on the client machine, on the server machine, somewhere in the middle, or you have some corporate proxy set in the browser. It has nothing to do with WebSphere settings if you can connect locally using hostname/ip.